# Where does Anaconda install libraries on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

Linux programmer here. I've installed some libraries such as Intell TBB on my Mac and am using Visual Studio Code to compile a source file that uses them:

```
#include "tbb/tbb.h"
#include "tbb/mutex.h"
```

But I get an error that these headers can't be found. Where are they installed and how can I tell VSC where to look for them.

Also is linking the same as in Linux?

Comment: Did you consider searching your file system to find these files? Provide the paths for include files using the `-I` compiler flag. _"Also is linking the same as in Linux?"_ Generally yes. You just have to specify the paths to resolve the libratries, and link these using the `-l` flags.

Comment: Can't you simply do a `find / -type f -iname "*tbb*"` (or similar) and find them? Then tell the compiler to search the location you found for includes/libraries (it has options/flags for that).

Answer (score 1):

They are installed where you installed TBB. Usually, that's in /opt/intel if you used Intel packages. Just like on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed using **homebrew** (which is generally a good idea since Apple doesn't provide any package management tools), you can see what files were installed where using:

```
brew ls tbb
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/include/tbb/ (109 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbb.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbbmalloc.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/cmake/ (2 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/python2.7/ (11 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/ (2 other files)
```

Sometimes it only tells you half the story, so use:

```
brew ls --verbose tbb
```

It generally links all includes and libraries into `/usr/local` too, so use:

```
ls -l /usr/local/{include,lib} | grep tbb
```

**Sample Output**

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    33 Sep 17  2018 tbb -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/include/tbb
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    34 Sep 17  2018 libtbb.a -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbb.a
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    38 Sep 17  2018 libtbb.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbb.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    40 Sep 17  2018 libtbbmalloc.a -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbbmalloc.a
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    44 Sep 17  2018 libtbbmalloc.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbbmalloc.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x    1 mark  admin    50 Sep 17  2018 libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib -> ../Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.dylib
```

Comment: i assume OP installed using Anaconda since the question is about Anaconda